# Insert break in data series of C# chart

Tags: c#, charts

I have several data series plotted on a chart. This is logged data spanning several hours. However, there is occasionally a period of 30 minutes where no data is logged. This causes the chart to draw a line between the last sample before logging stopped and the first sample when logging resumes.

This can appear quite misleading where sudden jumps in data appear. It is preferable to show that there is not logged data in this period.

Is there any way to tell the series not to plot data between two points? So it would still be one series, but with a break in the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking for microsoft chart controls for .net, you can add an empty data point. Add or create a DataPoint and set it's [IsEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.datapoint.isempty.aspx) property to true.

Note that you have to [configure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.series.emptypointstyle.aspx) the series to show the empty data points.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So do you recommend that I insert an empty point in the gaps where I want a break? The problem is that my `Series.Points` is empty - perhaps because I am setting the data using `chart.DataSource = table.DefaultView`

Comment: @Mark: Try the DataBound event. It also can be used to filter or sort datapoints: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedataboundcontrol.databound.aspx

Comment: My apologies - you are quite right. I needed to do this after data binding. I am now able to insert a point with `IsEmpty` set - and it works just as I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @HCL's answer, I think you have to set this property on the series itself in order to *show or not* missing points (for example when a Y value is `double.NaN`):

`series.IsXValueIndexed = true;//this allows to NOT draw missing points`

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.series.isxvalueindexed.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. From my understanding, this will simply close the gaps where there is missing data. Is this correct?

Comment: @Mark: it will close or open the gaps, depending on what you need. Quote from the above MSDN article: *For example, assume there are three (3) data points in a series having X-values of 1, 2 and 4. If this property was false, there would be a data point missing at the X-axis location labeled "3". However, if you set this property to true, the three data points will be plotted at points 1, 2, and 4, sequentially, and there will be no missing data point. The X-axis location labeled "3" will not appear on the chart.*

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the answer. I had not heard of this feature, so will remember it for the future. However, in this case I want it to be clear that there is missing data - so having the gap is beneficial.